Preloaded LiteSQL react-native expo
I've created a LiteSQL database filled with data, copied it to my repository, and tried to use it normally, but when trying to do anything with it, e.g., inserting new rows it says that the given column is not created which means instead of using pre-loaded db it is creating new one. So the question is how am i supposed to link pre-filled sqlite into my react-native expo-sql? Where do i need to place the file, or do i need some special initialization?
        const db = await SQLite.openDatabaseAsync('ElGatoDbLite');
        console.log(db);
        const result = await db.runAsync('INSERT INTO User (calories, protein, fat, carbs) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)', 33.3,22.2,11.1, 100);
        console.log(result.lastInsertRowId, result.changes);

